# SQL query to return only one record per non-unique key

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access 2010. My source table contains the following columns:

```
ID1

ID2 (ID1 + suffix)

Desc

Status

CancelDate

CancelCode

Amount
```

ID2 is treated as a unique ID (although there are a small amount of data-entry issues causing discrepancies, within tolerance).

Status contains three possible values - 1, 7 or T.

Within ID1 there can be multiple ID2s with different status.

CancelDate and CancelCode only exists on entries with status 7 or T.

What I'd like to achieve is for my query to return entries grouped by ID1. If any entries with ID1 have status 1, return any one of those entries. If however, none of the entries have status 1, return the record with the latest CancelDate.

I have this as my code now:

```
SELECT
    ID1,
    FIRST(Status) as Status,
    Desc,
    max(CancelDate) as MaxOfCancelDate,
    CancelCode,
    max(Amount) as Amount
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    ID1,
    Desc,
    CancelCode
```

I put FIRST because the source table is sorted where all records with status 1 comes before those with status 7 and T. This obviously does not do what I wish, and would return multiple records if a particular ID1 has entries with different status.

How can I achieve my goal?

I have a rough idea to `SELECT DISTINCT ID1` first, and join it with another sub-`SELECT`, but can't quite figure out how.

Thank you.

Comment: Your primary key is ID2 but it's not always unique? What on earth does "within tolerance" mean when it comes to databases?

Comment: Unfortunately the table is maintained by our IT dept, and out of close to a million records, there's <100 records that have duplicate ID2s. They are trying to fix it (and probably won't be anytime soon..), but I will need to work with what I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
(SELECT 
        First(ID1) AS ID1,
        Desc,
        CancelDate,
        CancelCode,
        max(Amount) as Amount
    FROM
        Table
    WHERE Status='1'
    GROUP BY
        Desc,
        CancelDate,
        CancelCode
    )

    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 
        ID1,
        Desc,
        Max(CancelDate) AS MaxCancelDate,
        CancelCode,
        max(Amount) as Amount
    FROM
        Table
    WHERE( Status='7' OR Status='T')
    GROUP BY
        ID1,
        Desc,
        CancelCode)
```

Comment: Thank you. This only returns the first record from both SELECTs though. Hmm